# Replace text with numbers using dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to replace months represented as a character (e.g. 'NOV') for their numerical counterparts ('-11-'). I can get the following piece of code to work properly.

```
df_cohorts['ltouch_datetime'] = df_cohorts['ltouch_datetime'].str.replace('NOV','-11-')
df_cohorts['ltouch_datetime'] = df_cohorts['ltouch_datetime'].str.replace('DEC','-12-')
df_cohorts['ltouch_datetime'] = df_cohorts['ltouch_datetime'].str.replace('JAN','-01-')
```

However, to avoid redundancy, I'd like to use a dictionary and .replace to replace the character variable for all months.

```
r_month1 = {'JAN':'-01-','FEB':'-02-','MAR':'-03-','APR':'-04-','MAY':'-05-','JUN':'-06-','JUL':'-07-','AUG':'-08-','SEP':'-09-','OCT':'-10-','NOV':'-11-','DEC':'-12-'}
df_cohorts.replace({'conversion_datetime': r_month1,'ltouch_datetime': r_month1})
```

When I enter the code above, my output dataset is unchanged. For reference, please see my sample data below.

```
User_ID    ltouch_datetime     conversion_datetime

001        11NOV14:13:12:56     11NOV14:16:12:00 
002        07NOV14:17:46:14     08NOV14:13:10:00 
003        04DEC14:17:46:14     04DEC15:13:12:00
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest a different approach: You could parse the date strings into a column of pandas TimeStamps like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
for col in ('ltouch_datetime', 'conversion_datetime'):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')

print(df)

#    User_ID     ltouch_datetime conversion_datetime
# 0        1 2014-11-11 13:12:56 2014-11-11 16:12:00
# 1        2 2014-11-07 17:46:14 2014-11-08 13:10:00
# 2        3 2014-12-04 17:46:14 2015-12-04 13:12:00
```

I would stop right here, since representing dates as TimeStamps is the ideal
form for the data in Pandas.

However, if you need/want date strings with 3-letter months like `'NOV'` converted to `-11-`, then you can convert the Timestamps with `strftime` and `apply`:

```
for col in ('ltouch_datetime', 'conversion_datetime'):
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%y:%H:%M:%S'))

print(df)
```

yields

```
   User_ID    ltouch_datetime conversion_datetime
0        1  11-11-14:13:12:56   11-11-14:16:12:00
1        2  07-11-14:17:46:14   08-11-14:13:10:00
2        3  04-12-14:17:46:14   04-12-15:13:12:00
```

---

To answer your question literally, in order to use `Series.str.replace` you need a column with the month string abbreviations all by themselves. You can arrange for that by first calling `Series.str.extract`. Then you can join the columns back into one using `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
month_map = {calendar.month_abbr[m].upper():'-{:02d}-'.format(m) 
             for m in range(1,13)}

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
for col in ('ltouch_datetime', 'conversion_datetime'):
    tmp = df[col].str.extract(r'(.*?)(\D+)(.*)')
    tmp[1] = tmp[1].replace(month_map)
    df[col] = tmp.apply(''.join, axis=1)

print(df)
```

yields

```
   User_ID    ltouch_datetime conversion_datetime
0        1  11-11-14:13:12:56   11-11-14:16:12:00
1        2  07-11-14:17:46:14   08-11-14:13:10:00
2        3  04-12-14:17:46:14   04-12-15:13:12:00
```

---

Finally, although you haven't asked for this directly, it's good to be aware
that if your data is in a file, you can parse the datestring columns into
TimeStamps *directly* using

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
df = pd.read_table(
    'data', sep='\s+', parse_dates=[1,2],
    date_parser=lambda x: DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'))
```

This might be the most convenient method of all (assuming you want TimeStamps).